# Как правильно: Telegram-канал или telegram-канал (со строчной)

Tags: орфография

Как правильно: Telegram-канал или telegram-канал (по аналогии с facebook-страница, где facebook -- приложение)?

На "Грамоте" при ответе (по другому вопросу) пишется: facebook-страница.